# Set IsReadOnlyProperty of a DataGridViewColumn whith DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik-grid

how can i set whole column to ReadOnly if a DataTemplate is used?
What i want is to turn off the selection of the whole combobox column, it should not be editable and selectable. The reason is that i want to turn off the selection of certain columns when a property is set in ViewModel.

I can also set the IsEnabled property of the combobox to a multibinding converter to achieve this goal. But is there a easier way to do this?

I have the following XAML:

The IsReadOnly property is set to True but the whole columns with the combobox stays selectable.

```
                  <ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn
                        Name="_colVariableType"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        Width="120"
                        ApplicationModelField="VariableType"
                        DataType="{Binding ColumnVariableDataType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Header="Variable Type"                                  
                        UniqueName="VariableType">

                        <ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadComboBox
                                    IsEditable="False"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=VariableType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VariableTypeOptions}"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsLocked, 
                                                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                                        Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
                                    IsManipulationEnabled="{Binding Path=IsLocked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" 
                                    />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>

                        <ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadComboBox
                                    IsEditable="False"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=VariableType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VariableTypeOptions}"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsLocked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
                                    IsManipulationEnabled="{Binding Path=IsLocked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    </ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn>
```

If i use the same code with a TextBox in it, everything works fine:

```
              <ffm:CustRadGridView.Columns>
                    <ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn
                        Name="_colName"
                        Width="200"
                        ApplicationModelField="Name"
                        Header="Name"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        UniqueName="Name">

                        <ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsLocked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
                                    IsManipulationEnabled="{Binding Path=IsLocked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
                                    Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>

                        <ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsLocked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
                                    IsManipulationEnabled="{Binding Path=IsLocked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"
                                    Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>

                    </ffm:CustRadGridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: When you set IsReadOnly on the Column, the CellEditTemplate is never in use. So when you say it works with the TextBox, what you see is that it never changes to the TextBox in the first place.

Comment: Hi thx for the answer. But if i Set the value to false. Then i can edit again. I have also replace the isenabled property of the text boxes to false or True in Order to only check the isreadonly property of the column.